# dup2 paramater order confusion

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, dup2

I have written this simple program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int fd = open("theFile.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if(fd<0){
     printf("coudlnt open File descriptor \n"); 
    }   
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){
        dup2(int oldFD, int newFD);
    dup2(fd,1);
        execlp("/bin/ls","ls","-l", NULL);      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What i want is, redirect the output of `ls - l` to a file called "theFile.txt". The code works as i expect. What confuses me here is the order of `dup2` parameters. I believe that correct order should be `dup2(1, fd)` - considering `fd` as the `newFD` and `1` as the `oldFD`. But the code works when i use it as `dup2(fd,1)` which basically is stdout to fd according to some other answers on SO.

How is the `oldFD` `fd` here and how is the `newFD` `1` here? If `1` is `newFD`, why does this program work in the first place?

Also, `execlp` overwrites child's address space after I call `dup2`. How is `dup2` connected to `execlp` such that the desired result is obtained. i.e. what i do `cat theFile.txt` i get the current directly listed.

Can i get some explanation here please?

Comment: Yes, the address space is overwritten, but the fds are preserved after an execXXX() call. see the manpages for execXXX() to see what is preserved after a call to execXXX().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[man7]: DUP(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html):

> **int dup2**(**int** *oldfd*, **int** *newfd*);
> ...
> The **dup**() system call creates a copy of the file descriptor *oldfd*,
> using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor for the new
> descriptor.
> ...
> The **dup2**() system call performs the same task as **dup**(), but instead
> of using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, it uses the file
> descriptor number specified in *newfd*. If the file descriptor *newfd*
> was previously open, it is silently closed before being reused.

When outputing data (e.g. text) to console, applications use the *stdout* stream (also *stderr*, but for simplicity's sake, let's leave that out). *stdout*'s *fileno* is **1** (it's better to use constants instead of values, as values might change - not very likely in **this** case, but in general):

> ```
> cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q048923791$ cat /usr/include/unistd.h | grep STDOUT
> #define   STDOUT_FILENO   1   /* Standard output.  */
> ```

In your child process, *ls* (via *execlp*) spits its data to *stdout* (fileno **1**). **Before** that, the *dup2* call is made. The current situation, **before** the *dup2* call (for clarity, I'm going to use the defined macro when referring to *stdout*'s *fileno*):

- *fd*: points to the custom file (opened previously)
- *STDOUT_FILENO*: points to *stdout*

The *dup2* call:

1. `dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO)` (as it is now): closes current *STDOUT_FILENO* and duplicates *fd* to *STDOUT_FILENO*. Current situation:

   - *fd*: points to the custom file
   - *STDOUT_FILENO*: points to the custom file
2. `dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, fd)`: closes current *fd* and duplicates *STDOUT_FILENO* to *fd*. Current situation:

   - *fd*: points to *stdout*
   - *STDOUT_FILENO*: points to *stdout*

As seen, for *#1.*, when data will be output to *stdout*, it will actually go to the custom file (as opposed to *#2.* where it would go to *stdout*, even when using *fd*).

Regarding the **2<sup>nd</sup>** question:

- [[man7]: EXEC(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html):

  > The **exec**() family of functions replaces the current process image
  > with a new process image.  The functions described in this manual
  > page are front-ends for [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).
- [[man7]: EXECVE(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

  > By default, file descriptors remain open across an **execve**().
  > ...
  > POSIX.1 says that if file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 would
  > otherwise be closed after a successful **execve**(), and the process
  > would gain privilege because the set-user-ID or set-group_ID mode
  > bit was set on the executed file, then the system may open an
  > unspecified file for each of these file descriptors.  As a general
  > principle, no portable program, whether privileged or not, can
  > assume that these three file descriptors will remain closed across
  > an **execve**().

The file descriptors will be passed from the child process to *ls*.

Here's an improved version (minor changes only) of your code (*code00.c*):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main() {
    int ret = 0, fd = open("thefile.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Coudln't open file: %d\n", errno);
        ret = 1;
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // dup2(int oldFD, int newFD);
        if (dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) {
            printf("Couldn't redirect stdout: %d\n", errno);
            ret = 2;
        }
        execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't spawn child process: %d\n", errno);
        ret = 3;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood it before the explanation and checked `cd /proc/<process number>` to see the `fd` and it started making sense! Thanks a lot for all the explanation :)